# jQuery on('click') not firing when other DOM element has not been loaded yet on iPad mobile safari

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, ipad

myI have a survey done in jQuery by another developer and I've come across one issue. When the survey is finished we have the option to restart the survey, our results page displays the link to restart the survey before the results of the survey are loaded on the page. This works fine in desktop browsers but iPad mobile Safari is not allowing this event to fire.

User Control:

```
 <section class="survey-section survey-results">                   
         <a href="#" class="survey-restart">Restart the Survey</a>

         <h1><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litResultsTitle"></asp:Literal></h1>                    
                <header class="survey-results-header">
                    <h2>Your Results</h2>
                </header>
                    <div class="survey-results-container">
                <PageEditor:DynamicKeyPlaceholder runat="server" ID="PhSurveyResults" Key="phsurveyresults" />
 </section>
```

jQuery:

```
mySite.displaySurveyResults = function (resultsType) {
    if (!resultsType) return;
    result = resultsType;
    $('.survey-results-' + resultsType).show();

    $("meta[property='og\\:description']").attr("content", $('.survey-results-' + resultsType +'.survey-results-content').html());

};
```

later on in the js file:

```
$('.survey-restart').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mySite.restartSurvey();
});
```

I've tried several workarounds including changing the cursor to pointer in the css, not using on('click'), but nothing seems to be working. I'm not sure how I should load the results before loading the "restart survey" link. Any help greatly appreciated!

The survey.js file is inserted into a footer placeholder in the user control, I've also tried moving this to the top of the user control:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phFooterScripts">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../something/something/survey.js"></script>
</asp:Placeholder>
```

Comment: Is the `'.survey-restart'` item in the page already when you try to install this event handler: `$('.survey-restart').on('click', function (e) {`?  You can put this right before it: `console.log($('.survey-restart').length)` to verify.  It should log non-zero if the item exists.

Comment: How does the '.survey-restart' item get into the page?  Where's the code that puts it in the page?  Is there a timing difference/issue with it being put into the page before or after your event handler?  If so, you can either fix the timing issue to have consistent behavior on all browsers or you can switch to using delegated event handling in which case you would only add the event handler once for all time and not readd it.

Comment: The console is outputting '1' on desktop, still not able to verify on iPad.

Comment: I guess you could temporarily change it to an `alert()` on iPad in order to see the number - though the `alert()` might alter the behavior of code that follows (it changes timing).

Comment: but on iPad it's not even clickable, I gave it a shot and it's not doing anything when clicked

Comment: What's not doing anything when clicked?  I don't understand what your last comment means.  Please answer my question above about how the `.survey-restart` item is put into the page?  You haven't yet disclosed enough info to get to the bottom of what is happening and why.

Comment: my apologies, the js file is inserted through a placeholder in the footer, I've also tried moving this to the top of the user control to no avail, I've edited my question, let me know what else I can provide to help in this.

Comment: Please describe how the `.survey-restart` DOM element gets inserted into your page.  I wasn't asking how a js file gets inserted, I was asking how this DOM element gets inserted.  Are you inserting a JS file which then itself inserts the DOM element?

Comment: This `.survey-restart` element is in a `DynamicKeyPlaceholder` which itself is inside a `class="survey-container"`, the item is not inserted from the JS file

Comment: I guess I can't help further because I don't know what a `DynamicKeyPlaceholder` is or what it does so I still don't know how `.survey-restart` gets into your page.  It's not a standard part of JS or browser.  Must be something in your framework?

Comment: Yes, it's part of the Sitecore CMS we work under, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

> jQuery on('click') not firing when other DOM element has not been loaded yet on iPad mobile safari

Of course not, you can't hook an event handler on an element if the element doesn't exist yet.

You have two choices:

1. Wait to hook the event until the element exists, or
2. Use event delegation to hook `click` on a container element that already exists (`document`, in the worst case):

   ```
   $("selector for container").on("click", ".survey-restart", function(e) { 
       // ...
   });
   ```

   jQuery handles all the plumbing there for you, so it's very much like you'd hooked the event on the actual `survey-restart` element.

Comment: If this is the case, then why does it work on desktop browser?

Comment: @jfriend00: I expect it's a timing issue.

Comment: Might be right, but you're making wild guesses at a fix without getting to the bottom of the actual cause.

Comment: @jfriend00: I disagree, the two things above are fundamental. If the element doesn't exist, you can't directly hook to it; if you want, you can use event delegation, and that will kick in when the element actually exists.

Comment: But you haven't established why the element doesn't exist on iPad, but does exist everywhere else.  Whatever.  I thought some questions were in order to establish some facts before jumping to a solution.  I guess I just think it's better to know exactly what's going on and why before changing code.

Comment: event delegation didn't seem to resolve the issue, the container becomes "clickable" but the event does not fire